# ToDictionary Querying from second table returns Null

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, repository-pattern

I have two models as below:

```
public class Complaint
{
    [Key]
    public int COMP_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> Received_DT { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CHECKLIST> CHECKLISTs { get; set; }
}


public class CHECKLIST
{
    [Key]
    public int CL_ID { get; set; }
    public int EmpID { get; set; }
    public virtual COMPLAINT Complaints { get; set; }
}
```

I have a repository that queries and returns counts of all the checklist entered in by EMPID but when I add another filter from the parent table of .Where, it returns null. When I take out the .Where clause from the parent table, it works just fine.

**Edit** Attempted including the table

```
public Dictionary<int, int> GetAllChecklistCount()
    {
        try
        {
            return _context.Checklists
                .Where(t => t.Complaints.Received_DT.Value.Year == 2016) 
                .Include(t => t.Complaints)
                .GroupBy(a => a.EmpID)
                .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Could not get am with checklist", ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Error being thrown**

> Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll System.ArgumentException: Expression of type System.Func`2[Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor+TransparentIdentifier`2[CRAMSV3_2.Models.CHECKLIST,Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.ValueBuffer],System.Int32]' cannot be used for parameter of type System.Func`2[CRAMSV3_2.Models.CHECKLIST,System.Int32]' 
>   of method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.Int32,CRAMSV3_2.Models.CHECKLIST]] 
>   _GroupBy[CHECKLIST,Int32,CHECKLIST](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[CRAMSV3_2.Models.CHECKLIST], System.Func`2[CRAMSV3_2.Models.CHECKLIST,System.Int32], System.Func`2[CRAMSV3_2.Models.CHECKLIST,CRAMSV3_2.Models.CHECKLIST])'

**Question** What is the best way to return results with multiple tables or just one table but making sure the dates from another table are Queryable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to Include the Complaints object.

```
return _context.Checklists
            .Where(t => t.Complaints.Received_DT.Value.Year == 2016)
            .Include(t => t.Complaints)
            .GroupBy(a => a.EmpID)
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) for details

Comment: Thank you Dean, I attempted including the table but I am still getting null and the error I am getting is: Exception thrown: System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll

Comment: I have updated with my thrown exception, and have no idea how to decipher it.

Comment: It's a tough one to parse for sure.  I see that Received_DT is nullable, so the above code isn't necessarily safe.  Try with some extra checks in the Where:

.Where(t => t.Complaints != null && t.Complaints.Received_DT.HasValue && t.Complaints.Received_DT.Value.Year == 2016)

Comment: I have actually tried that. I'll keep trying. Thank you.

Comment: What version of EF?  Your stacktrace and query looks a lot like the one in this issue: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4318

Perhaps try returning the results of the GroupBy.ToList() and then converting to dictionary?